# Import-Module System.Management.Automation

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, module, powershell-cmdlet

I'm attempting to write a binary PowerShell module, following some online tutorials. My project is targeting .NET Core 3.1 and I have added the latest stable System.Management.Automation package (7.0.3) which states .NET core 3.1 as a dependency.

I can compile the project fine, but when I attempt to import the module with the 'Import-Module' cmdlet I receive the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version 7.0.3.0". I have Powershell 7 installed.

Any hints on what I need to do to get this working?

Thanks,
John

Comment: "I have Powershell 7 installed." do you have PowerShell _7.0.3_ (latest release) installed?

Comment: Yes, 7.0.3 (Get-Host | Select-Object Version)

Comment: @John: Am also facing the similar issue if issue is resolved may i know what's the resolution for it?